# Android Garbage Collector Metronome App

Tags: android, garbage-collection, java-native-interface

I have a metronome app and whenever the gc starts its is delayed for 50ms on my Nexus4, although this almost isn't noticeable I guess it's worse on older devices and some people even notice the 50ms delay.
I THINK that I have optimized the code pretty well, the gc only kicks in every 5 - 10 seconds.
Could someone suggest a way to 'fix' this ?
Do threads written with the NDK get paused by the gc, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you handle the sound on a separate thread (even if it's a Java thread) where 0 allocations happen,  then GC launched on another thread will not delay it.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, remove those remaining allocations.  You won't have to stop to collect garbage if there's none to collect.  The DDMS/ADT [Allocation Tracker](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/track-memory-allocations.html) feature can help you track them down.  (Note it *is* available in the ADT Eclipse plugin now.)

Pure-native threads are not paused by the GC, though they can still fight with the GC for the CPU.  If the thread calls back into the VM, though, it will pause if a GC is in progress.